# Почему google выдает ошибку сканирования sitemap на django?

Tags: python, django, sitemap, google-search

Я сделал сайт на джанго и добавил sitemap - вначале гугл сканирвал sitemap, но потом перестал - статус - Не получено, общая ошибка http

При переходе на сайт карта работает.
https://wherefilmed.org/sitemap.xml

Robots.txt есть и разрешает все.

Sitemap.py

```
class DynamicViewSitemapEn(Sitemap):
    changefreq = 'weekly'
    alternates = False
    i18n = True
    limit = 1000

    def items(self):
        return Movies.objects.all()

    def location(self, item):
        return f'/en/movies/{item.slug}/'

class DynamicViewSitemapRu(Sitemap):

    def items(self):
        return Movies.objects.all()

    def location(self, item):
        return f'/ru/movies/{item.slug}/'
```

Comment: в robots.txt добавьте `Host: https://wherefilmed.org` и `Sitemap: https://wherefilmed.org/sitemap.xml`

Comment: ну и _Не получено, общая ошибка http_ может означать, что где-то запрет на доступ гугла к вашему сайту, может у вас на хостинге, может у провайдера, может у гугла. Если "свежий" домен, то может изменения dns еще не докатились до гугла

Comment: Да, обновление robots.txt помогло, спасибо!

Answer (score 0):

Помог ответ в комментарии:
в файл robots.txt необходимо добавить

```
Host: https://wherefilmed.org
Sitemap: https://wherefilmed.org/sitemap.xml
```